# Deallocating RTCMediaStream blocks the main Thread

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading, webrtc

I'm building an iOS app that should use the WebRTC implementation form [webrtc.org](http://webrtc.org). I created the demo app and every thing works fine. After integrating the framework into my own app I'm experiencing a problem regarding deallocating resources.

As a first step I wanted to create a local media stream and add an audio and video track to it. In my tests I realized, that deallocating a `RTCMediaStream` (and `VideoTrackProxy`) object blocks the main thread for about 10 seconds.

To reproduce this, I created a separate test, that creates a media stream adds a video track to it and deallocates it afterwards (objects are released at the end of the scope).

```
@interface RTCTests : XCTestCase
@property (nonatomic, strong) RTCPeerConnectionFactory *factory;
@end

@implementation RTCTests

- (void)setUp
{
    [super setUp];
    self.factory = [[RTCPeerConnectionFactory alloc] init];
}

- (void)tearDown
{
    self.factory = nil;
    [super tearDown];
}

- (void)testLocalMediaStream
{
    RTCMediaStream *mediaStream = [self.factory mediaStreamWithLabel:@"stream-a"];

    XCTestExpectation *expectation = [self expectationWithDescription:@"Create Media Stream"];

    [AVCaptureDevice requestAccessForMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo
                             completionHandler:^(BOOL granted){
                                 dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

                                     if (granted == NO) {
                                         XCTFail(@"Access to camera not granted.");
                                         [expectation fulfill];
                                     } else {

                                         NSString *cameraID = nil;
                                         for (AVCaptureDevice *captureDevice in [AVCaptureDevice devicesWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo]) {
                                             if (captureDevice.position == AVCaptureDevicePositionFront) {
                                                 cameraID = [captureDevice localizedName];
                                                 break;
                                             }
                                         }

                                         if (cameraID) {
                                             RTCVideoCapturer *capturer = [RTCVideoCapturer capturerWithDeviceName:cameraID];
                                             RTCMediaConstraints *mediaConstraints = [[RTCMediaConstraints alloc] initWithMandatoryConstraints:@[]
                                                                                                                           optionalConstraints:@[]];
                                             RTCVideoSource *videoSource = [self.factory videoSourceWithCapturer:capturer
                                                                                                     constraints:mediaConstraints];

                                             RTCVideoTrack *track = [self.factory  videoTrackWithID:@"stream-a-v" source:videoSource];
                                             if (track) {
                                                 [mediaStream addVideoTrack:track];
                                             }
                                         }

                                         [expectation fulfill];
                                     }
                                 });
                             }];

    [self waitForExpectationsWithTimeout:10.0 handler:^(NSError *error) {
        XCTAssertNil(error, @"Failed with error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
    }];

    XCTAssertEqual([mediaStream.videoTracks count], 1);
    XCTAssertEqualObjects([[[mediaStream videoTracks] firstObject] label], @"stream-a-v");

    NSLog(@"Done! %@", [NSDate date]);
}

@end
```

The test itself works as expected and it succeeds more or less immediately as you can see in the log below:

```
Test Case '-[RTCTests testLocalMediaStream]' started.
2015-03-02 14:51:36.458 App[9043:2810016] Begin! 2015-03-02 13:51:36 +0000
2015-03-02 14:51:36.643 App[9043:2810016] End! 2015-03-02 13:51:36 +0000
Test Case '-[RTCTests testLocalMediaStream]' passed (9.266 seconds).
```

But it takes another 9 seconds to deallocate the resources (in this case the `VideoTrackProxy`) which synchronously calls a method on an other thread in the destructor (if I read the [sources of the proxy](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/codesearch#chromium/src/third_party/libjingle/source/talk/app/webrtc/proxy.h) correctly). Unfortunately this thread seams to be the main thread, which results in a dead lock and is resolved by a timeout I guess.

```
* thread #1: tid = 0x2ae4a8, 0x00000001978db078 libsystem_kernel.dylib`__psynch_cvwait + 8, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = signal SIGSTOP
  * frame #0: 0x00000001978db078 libsystem_kernel.dylib`__psynch_cvwait + 8
    frame #1: 0x0000000197976fe4 libsystem_pthread.dylib`_pthread_cond_wait + 624
    frame #2: 0x0000000100cbc2c0 RTCTests`rtc::Event::Wait(int) + 232
    frame #3: 0x0000000100b210cc RTCTests`webrtc::VideoTrackProxy::~VideoTrackProxy() + 120
    frame #4: 0x0000000100b206b0 RTCTests`rtc::RefCountedObject::~RefCountedObject() + 12
    frame #5: 0x0000000100b20690 RTCTests`rtc::RefCountedObject::Release() + 52
    frame #6: 0x0000000197152b1c libobjc.A.dylib`object_cxxDestructFromClass(objc_object*, objc_class*) + 148
    frame #7: 0x000000019715ff38 libobjc.A.dylib`objc_destructInstance + 92
    frame #8: 0x000000019715ff90 libobjc.A.dylib`object_dispose + 28
    frame #9: 0x0000000100b58db4 RTCTests`-[RTCMediaStreamTrack(Internal) dealloc] + 92
    frame #10: 0x0000000100b5ef6c RTCTests`-[RTCVideoTrack dealloc] + 356
    frame #11: 0x000000018692d228 CoreFoundation`CFRelease + 524
    frame #12: 0x0000000186935308 CoreFoundation`-[__NSArrayI dealloc] + 88
    frame #13: 0x000000019716d724 libobjc.A.dylib`(anonymous namespace)::AutoreleasePoolPage::pop(void*) + 564
    frame #14: 0x00000001011f1c54 XCTest`-[XCTestCase invokeTest] + 336
    ...
```

Can the WebRTC framework be configured to not use the main thread for its internal tasks? Or am I missing something else here?

I'm appreciating all kinds of tips.

Comment: @SevenDays I had the same issue, but it turned out that at deinitialization point the instance of `RTCPeerConnectionFactory` should be explicitly deinitialized after streams and tracks instances. Factory keeps all threads for network and signalling work, so when stream deinitialization reaches some async work on signalling thread it hangs, as thread was destroyed alongside with factory

Comment: i dont think so, i found webrtc swift got alert in the log, ASAP it running, so I think it's block mainthread when rtc running